# How do I properly use Oracle Flashback to audit table changes with user information?

Tags: oracle, plsql, audit, audit-logging, flashback

My organization has chosen to use Oracle Flashback to replace manually created audit tables.  However, the DBA set the `TUNED_AUTORETENTION` values and `UNDO_RETENTION` to only 14400 seconds.  Unfortunately, we have to keep the audit values for  7 years on this data. Is there a way to query "expired" version data so specific changes can be audited by timespan, or does `UNDO_RETENTION` and the individual `TUNED_AUTORETENTION` values need to be set to 220800000? I looked into `flashback_transaction_query` but it only shows the transaction general data, not which column values were changed.

The database in question currently has its tablespace files set to automatically allocate more physical layer space on the logical drive.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you should be using Flashback Data Archive, not basic Flashback. The parameters you mentioned only apply to basic flashback.

> A Flashback Data Archive provides the ability to track and store
> transactional changes to a table over its lifetime. A Flashback Data
> Archive is useful for compliance with record stage policies and audit
> reports.

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-06AA782A-3F79-4235-86D5-2D136485F093

Comment: Flashback Data Archive is what my department intended to use.   However, when executing a query, the XID is not preserved in the VERSIONS_XID column, and it appears that other Version and transaction data is also lost.   We can see the table values, but not when they changed or who changed them.

Comment: what query are you using to view the archived versions? And what steps were taken to enable archiving on your table(s)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the final scripts to enable were handled by the offsite host and the request to enable went through a couple of layers of management and approval, so I can't be 100% sure.   The code we ran to enable was just things like ALTER TABLE Billing.INVOICE_PRICE FLASHBACK ARCHIVE FIN_AUDIT_7Y; .  This is how we discovered there was no XID: 
    SELECT billing.INVOICE_PRICE.*
    , NVL(VERSIONS_STARTTIME, '') CHANGE_DATE
    , NVL(VERSIONS_OPERATION, 'I') OPERATION
    , VERSIONS_XID
     FROM billing.INVOICE_PRICE
    VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE

Comment: hmmm. something doesn't sound right, but this might require the assistance of Oracle Support to sort out. VERSION_XID should be populated.

Comment: Would those retention variables come into play if the tablespace datafiles were not set with AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT nG; ?

Comment: No. They only apply to basic flashback, not to flashback archive. The autoextend just allows the data files to grow as you accumulate more data. If you turned it off, it would freeze the files at their current size and potentially cause something to hang when you ran out of room.